# Creating Azure Storage Account VerySlow

Tags: azure, azure-storage

We are testing a set of PS scripts to create several Azure artifacts:
- Storage Accounts
- SQL Servers
- Service Bus
- App Services
- AppInsights
- IOT Hub

The performance is very variable.  For example, sometimes creating the StorageAccounts take a second or three (we create 2), and sometimes it takes 20 minutes+.  All our resources are in US East; we are using the `New-AzureRmxxx` PS commands.

Is this typical?  How do others investigate such issues in addition to confirming there are no outages via the Azure Health dashboards?

Comment: Do you use the latest Azure PowerShell version. `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh` check your version. The latest version is 4.1.0. You could use `-Verbose` to get the detailed process when your script is executing.

Answer (score 0):

First off all, Azure had this problem with storage account creation lately, but it appears to be gone (at least at the time of writing).

The other problem you might be facing - creating storage accounts (or any resources for that matter) in place of the ones you've just deleted. So you have a storage account named `mystorageacct`, you deleted it in the script and right after that you are starting to create it with the same name, that can take a while because of how Azure works.

And generally you don't troubleshoot behavior like this in the cloud. Cloud is meant to throw timeouts every now and then. If you would be creating unique named storage accounts every time this wouldn't be an issue. And if Azure has got some problems, those are temporary and nothing you can do about them (but knowing about them helps). Here's the [RSS feed](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/).

Answer (score 0):

I have observed this behavior when using DevOps to recreate a Resource Group.
If I purge(Remove) the resources and then attempt to recreate them using the same name, this causes slowness.

I found if I delete the Resource Group in it's entirety, then recreate it and the accompanying resources, the slowness does not bite as often.